# Convert lowercase to uppercase in the case of excel file using shell script

Tags: shell, uppercase, lowercase

I am able to convert lower case to upper case for CSV files.

Code example:

```
tmpf=`tempfile`.csv
cat $3 | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"  | tr -d "\\r\\000" > $tmpf
sed -i -e '1,1s/, $//' $tmpf
echo -n $tmpf
```

How can I do the same for Excel files?

Comment: You will need to save the excel file as text or csv first. Why? the file format used by MS also contains numerous additional sections, formatting, etc. and attempting to change case throughout the file would cause a number of problems.

Comment: I have re named tmpf=`tempfile`.xlsx

Comment: but still not working

Comment: Well, renaming isn't exactly the same thing as `File->Save As->` choose new name, and choose Type `'Plain Text'` or `'Comma Separated Values'` from the file type list. That will export the file in a text format you can convert. You may also be able to do a Global Search/Replace inside Excel and choose the special formatting options which may include TitleCase.

Comment: If you want to preserve the spreadsheet (you lose info if you convert to text,) use vba or vbscript.  There are quite a few answered questions for vbscript and Excel, on SO and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to download the ssconvert 
You have to convert your excel file to csv using ssconvert 
Edit your code

```
tmpf=`tempfile`.csv
ssconvert "pathtoyourexcelfile" "pathtoyourcsvfile"
cat $3 | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"  | tr -d "\\r\\000" > $tmpf
sed -i -e '1,1s/, $//' $tmpf
echo -n $tmpf
```